# Initial bias values for a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, bias-neuron

I am currently building a CNN in tensorflow and I am initialising my weight matrix using a He normal weight initialisation. However, I am unsure how I should initialise my bias values. I am using ReLU as my activation function between each convolutional layer. Is there a standard method to initialising bias values?

```
# Define approximate xavier weight initialization (with RelU correction described by He)
def xavier_over_two(shape):
    std = np.sqrt(shape[0] * shape[1] * shape[2])
    return tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=std)

def bias_init(shape):
    return #???
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **Initializing the biases.** It is possible and common to initialize the
>   biases to be zero, since the asymmetry breaking is provided by the
>   small random numbers in the weights. For ReLU non-linearities, some
>   people like to use small constant value such as 0.01 for all biases
>   because this ensures that all ReLU units fire in the beginning and
>   therefore obtain and propagate some gradient. However, it is not clear
>   if this provides a consistent improvement (in fact some results seem
>   to indicate that this performs worse) and it is more common to simply
>   use 0 bias initialization.

source: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 13):

Be aware of the specific case of the last layer's bias. As Andrej Karpathy explains in his [Recipe for Training Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/):

> **init well.** Initialize the final layer weights correctly. E.g. if you are regressing some values that have a mean of 50 then initialize the final bias to 50. If you have an imbalanced dataset of a ratio 1:10 of positives:negatives, set the bias on your logits such that your network predicts probability of 0.1 at initialization. **Setting these correctly will speed up convergence and eliminate “hockey stick” loss curves where in the first few iteration your network is basically just learning the bias.**

Comment: An explanation for the examples Karpathy made can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/606498/271266)