# Follow-up to "In PyTorch how are layer weights and biases initialized by default?"

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

In the answer with most voted of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529625/in-pytorch-how-are-layer-weights-and-biases-initialized-by-default), it says:

> Most layers are initialized using [Kaiming Uniform](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_) method. Example layers include Linear, Conv2d, RNN etc.

I was actually wondering: Where does one know this from? For example, I would like to know the default initialization of `torch.nn.Conv2d` and `torch.nn.BatchNorm2d` for PyTorch 1.9.0. For `torch.nn.Linear`, I found the answer [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L92:L100) (from the second answer of the above mentioned question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional modules such as [`nn.Conv1d`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L173), [`nn.Conv2d`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L304), and [`nn.Conv3d`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L448) inherit from the [`_ConvNd`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8535418a06d75025541370cc656a8b6a0330ca0d/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L43) class. This class has a [`reset_parameters`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8535418a06d75025541370cc656a8b6a0330ca0d/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L140) function implemented just like `nn.Linear`:

```
def reset_parameters(self) -> None:
    # Setting a=sqrt(5) in kaiming_uniform is the same as initializing with
    # uniform(-1/sqrt(k), 1/sqrt(k)), where k = weight.size(1) * prod(*kernel_size)
    # For more details see: 
    # https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15314#issuecomment-477448573
    init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
    if self.bias is not None:
        fan_in, _ = init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
        bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
        init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)
```

As for `nn.BatchNorm2d`, it has [`reset_parameters`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c371542efc31b1abfe6f388042aa3ab0cef935f2/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py#L64) and [`reset_running_stats`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c371542efc31b1abfe6f388042aa3ab0cef935f2/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py#L56) function:

```
def reset_parameters(self) -> None:
    self.reset_running_stats()
    if self.affine:
        init.ones_(self.weight)
        init.zeros_(self.bias)

def reset_running_stats(self) -> None:
    if self.track_running_stats:
        # running_mean/running_var/num_batches... are registered at runtime depending
        # if self.track_running_stats is on
        self.running_mean.zero_()  # type: ignore[operator]
        self.running_var.fill_(1)  # type: ignore[operator]
        self.num_batches_tracked.zero_()  # type: ignore[operator]
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer! I had actually also been searching for the `reset_parameters` function on GitHub, but I had missed that there is a separate file called `conv.py` on GitHub. I would have one question to the initialization of the bias because it says in the paper "Delving Deep into Rectifiers:
Surpassing Human-Level Performance on ImageNet Classification" on page 4: 
"[...] We also initialize **b** = 0." 
But this is not done for the bias term as the code suggests that you shared. Do you know why not?

Comment: I think you will find this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883861/initial-bias-values-for-a-neural-network) interesting. It discusses the differences between the two initialization methods.